# Logstash - Import module inside ruby filter

Tags: ruby, logstash, logstash-configuration

I'm trying to use a ruby code within a logstash filter, but it gives an error:

```
filter {
    ruby {
        code => "
arr = [ {id: 1, name: 'John' }, {id: 2, name: 'Sam' }, {id: 3, name: 'Bob' }]
if arr.any? {|h| h[:name] == "Sam"}
event['doc']['userInput']['programName'] = '222222'
end"
         }
      }
```

I assume that the error is because I need to import the Enumerable module (beucase without the line `arr.any? {|h| h[:name] == "Sam"}` no error is thrown), but I have no idea how to import a module inside logstash's ruby filter?

Comment: The problem is because `Sam` is between double quotes, you need to use single quotes in the whole code block since the code is surrounded with double quotes itself.

Comment: @Val - Thank you so much, you solved it! If you write your comment as an answer I'll defenitly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because `Sam` is between double quotes, you need to use single quotes in the whole code block since the code is surrounded with double quotes itself.

```
filter {
ruby {
    code => "
       arr = [ {id: 1, name: 'John' }, {id: 2, name: 'Sam' }, {id: 3, name: 'Bob' }]
       if arr.any? {|h| h[:name] == 'Sam'}
          event['doc']['userInput']['programName'] = '222222'
       end"
     }
  }
```